# Regular expression - check for integer does not work

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple problem of checking a regular expression for integer value. I found from this site the following:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script language="JavaScript">
function check_integer(el) {
var intRegex = /^d+$/;
    var num=el.value;
    if(!intRegex.test(num)) {
      alert('must be an integer.');
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="f" onchange="check_integer(this)">
</form>
</body></html>
```

If I type 5 in the box and then click outside the box, it says not an integer. Tried on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: `/\d+$/` this is correct I suppose.

Comment: From what question exactly did you pick that up? Seems like it needs a correction too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Syntax error:

```
var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
                -^-
```

`\d` means "digit". If you don't escape it, it means literally `d`. Learn more here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: ouch. thanks. the \ must have been taken out by database. yep - there was a stripslashes. thnx